# Can't decode base64 image from a text file using java

Tags: java, base64, decode

I'm currently trying to decode an image from Base64 using this method, but it never gets the getProperty() method

```
Image icon = null;
Properties properties = ReadProperties.readFromConfig("img/icon.properties");
System.setProperty("jagacy.properties.dir", "src/test/resources/img");
byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(properties.getProperty("icon"));
icon = Image.getInstance(decoded);
```

icon.properties files contains the following:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAAcUlEQVRIiWNgGAVkgqMMDAz/ScSHsRnEiMOC/2Q6DMM8FlI14AA4HcREpAFkg1ELCAJCkUxuaoIDXD44SIZZWPMBqQCWqYgGdI9kQkUEDBBdZKBb8I8KjiYqCEkNa5zqh35GG7CcfISBtDggVf0oQAAAu0ctGvdYYksAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

[here's the picture that it's supposed to be decoded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIvqL.png)

So far I've only tried to decode Base64 in both plain text and URI but both end up the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more tests, the answer ended up being removing the `image/png;base64,` from the text file and modify the code, so the working code looks like this:

```
Image icon = null;
Properties properties = ReadProperties.readFromConfig("img/icon.properties");
System.setProperty("jagacy.properties.dir", "src/test/resources/img");
byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(properties.getProperty("data")); //<-- changed from "icon" 
icon = Image.getInstance(decoded);
```

and the icon.properties files contains the following:

```
data:iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAAcUlEQVRIiWNgGAVkgqMMDAz/ScSHsRnEiMOC/2Q6DMM8FlI14AA4HcREpAFkg1ELCAJCkUxuaoIDXD44SIZZWPMBqQCWqYgGdI9kQkUEDBBdZKBb8I8KjiYqCEkNa5zqh35GG7CcfISBtDggVf0oQAAAu0ctGvdYYksAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```